# How can I beat Rainbow Summit?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

So I've recently had some time off work and I've been playing my way through all the scenarios that I have never completed before. I have two left - Extreme Heights - which, as it has unlimited money, should be fine, given the time, and Rainbow Summit.

The goal is 2,500 guests in attendance by the end of Year 4. Typically, this would be no issue however the park prevents advertising campaigns (as well as not allowing to build above tree height).

I have three high-capacity roller-coasters, one mid-capacity coaster, one large capacity rather plain monorail, and a number of gentle and thrill rides. The park is basically an -E| shape, where the path comes from the entrance, splits, and goes in front of the mountain. The paths then tunnel in through the mountain before meeting at the top in the middle, with a path leading back to the entrance.

When I started the scenario, I spend a lot of time demolishing the trams and chairlift and building pathways/toilets/food stalls, etc, and put a few gentle/thrill rides by the entrance to keep people happy. My park (as the pictures will show) is quite spread out, so am I Doing This Wrong and need to cram as many attractions in as possible?

The best I have is May, Year 4, with 1,700 guests. I have no idea how to increase attendance (and I have no wish to cheat with something like 7 Cars Per Trainer to spam guests into the park).

Even with those 1.7k guests, I have around 50 complaining the park is too crowded, even though all my main pathways are double-width so I have no idea how I would keep my park rating high with 2.5k.

I know RCT2 is quite old now, but I'd like to say I've completed all scenarios without cheating. How should I handle this park?

(sorry for odd images, it seems the screenshots were taken at a resolution that didn't match my monitor).

[image] - [click for bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsXK9.png)

[image] - [click for bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hsSK.png)

Comment: I don't quite remember that scenario, but can you build go-karts? They are so broken that a simple square attracts everyone.

Comment: Can you do the old cheeky "No entry sign near the entrance to stop people leaving?

Comment: @franglais, yes, although the park rating tends to drop quite severely once you do so. Thing is, I've had 2000 guests come through my gates, so 300 have left. I'm still 500 short.

Comment: Shuttle-Loops... All Shuttle-Loops :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This scenario is one of the hardest Expert scenarios in RCT2. If you complete all of the Challenging scenarios, Rainbow Summit will be much easier for you. The fact that you can't build tall coasters is the main reason for that.

Start easy by building stalls, gentle and thrill rides available. Don't use the tracked rides at all in this scenario, because you will find yourself struggling to find space later on. 4 years is a lot of time to build, the question is how.

This scenario will force you to be creative, if you build coasters on the ground, use the mini-small ones, because the are limited in heights without the scenario tree-height-limit.

After you fill your park with thrill rides and small coasters, increase your park entrance fee to $40. Don't worry, they will pay for that. Charge the guests $3 for drinks and food, an make restrooms cost 10 cents. This won't bring in profit, but will decrease the expenses for restrooms. Charge umbrellas for $10, because guests still will be happy to give you money just to be dry during a storm.

Now, build a roller coaster smartly, using the ground of the summit to build the coaster to gain height, that is the only source of gaining height in this scenario, so be sure to use space smart, after that so you won't get a high neusea rating of your coaster you need to be creative, it won't be hard if you use gentle drops instead of steep drops, your roller coaster will still be interesting if you build interesting ride, now raise the entrance fee to $45, and keep it in this price for the entire length of the scenario, or guests won't be able to pay to enter the park.

Keep building coasters in this system and you will continually bring guests into your park. Create at least 7 more coasters and you should be okay for the rest of the scenario. Building underground is a good idea if you are low on space above ground. Scenery, tunnels and water always give you extra excitement. As long your coasters are above 6 excitement rating, more guests will come to your park.

Keep your rating high regularly and get extra guests by getting awards. In year 4, start repaying your loan. This level does not allow campaigning, so in order to keep guests coming in you need to frequently build new rides. The guests usually stay in this park due to little rain, so as long as you keep them happy with enough bathrooms, food stalls, and entertainers, your guest amount should not decrease.

If you beat the all the scenarios of the RCT2 and kept this one to the end, this scenario will be easy for you, and you will be happy with the result, as you finished all the scenarios of the original RCT2.

[Source](http://rct.wikia.com/wiki/Rainbow_Summit)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't reccomend deleting rides at the start, as many guests are brought in by gentle rides in this park as well as coasters.  I noticed you destroyed the tram only to create a monorail that has the same effect.  Don't waste valuable time on "vanilla deals" like this.

As one guys said earlier, build cheap roller coasters at the start.  You can start with a couple of the cat/mouse coasters.  These can easily net you 6.00 excitement while costing under $5000.

Also, you need to spend more money dude.  There's $60 000 available in this scenario.  If you're not concerned with the financial wellbeing of your park after yr 4, you should use all of this, wisely, to build coasters that bring in guests.  I wouldn't worry about paying back your loan if you only care about the completion.

Answer (score 1):

One key: more coaster, more rides; more awards.
Apparently the screenshot of this park is very empty. You must continue to expand. If time is running short, make a back up for making draft as designing ride track or observing park operation after something is done. Use formal save to make change as all treatment preview is settled.